# new to rails, setting up db then running rake db:create/migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, migrate

hi im currently learning rails, and following a tutorial. the instructions were to edit the migration file after i've created the app, then running rake db:migrate, then rake db:create.

i've edited the migration file to this:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :username
      t.string :email
      t.string :encrypted_password
      t.string :salt
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

then when i've run 'rake db:migrate' i got an error

```
Mysql2::Error: Table 'users' already exists: CREATE TABLE `users` ...
```

after i'm supposed to run 'rake db:create', then im getting this

```
user_auth_development already exists
user_auth_test already exists
```

Comment: do i need to run db:create and db:migrate? or is this alreay setup once i edit the migrate file?

Comment: It means the table already exists. May be a previous migration already created it.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You run `rake db:create` once and only once, and you run it first.  Then you run `rake db:migrate` every time you add/change a migration.  You've either already run this migration, or you are pointing at a database that already exists and already contains a table named `users`.  My guess is that you ran the migration once already, in which case you're probably good to go.  If you want to nuke the DB and start over, do `rake db:drop db:create db:migrate`.

Comment: Thanks so much! I don't know why they don't cover this in the guides. Neither does it explain how exactly you go about updating migrations correctly. When I update the migrate file and run `rake db:migrate` nothing happens. I know I'm doing something wrong, but I don't know what I should be doing. Do I have to give the migration a new name or something?

Comment: Generally speaking, you shouldn't modify a migration file. If you really know what you're doing, you'll know when it's acceptable. If you have any doubts, don't modify; instead, make a new migration file (`rails generate migration`). There's one minor exception to this: if you want to modify the most-recent migration, you can do so, and then run `rake db:migrate:redo`, which will drop and rerun the last migration. This isn't always possible; it depends on the last migration being reversible (not all are). You shouldn't do this if you've already committed it to a shared repository.

Comment: The reason it did nothing is because Rails keeps track of which migrations have been run. It creates a table called `schema_migrations`, which contains a list of migration timestamps (the initial numeric part of a migration name). It won't re-run one that's already recorded there. That's how it knows which migrations to apply when you run `rake db:migrate`.

Answer (score 21):

We can simply give, it will do all the rake task which is require for database creation and migration

**`rake db:setup`**

Comment: Have been looking for that simple piece of information quite a bit... Was too trivial to find it easily it seems. It will generate the database from the models.

Answer (score 1):

For Rails 5 and 6, the command is:

```
rails setup
```

This will "*create the database, load the schema, and initialize it with the seed data*" ([docs](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#setup-the-database)).

Comment: Maybe `rails db:setup`?

Answer (score 0):

For rails 6 & above, you can give this command to **create** a database, **migrate** all the migration files, and **seed** the data into the database:

```
rails db:prepare
```